# Webdriver.io, JS. Выделение нескольких элементов с помощью CTRL + клик

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

В рамках теста необходимо проверит корректность выделения сразу нескольких строк таблицы с помощью CTRL+клик по элементу. Пыталась то реализовать с помощью browser.performActions(), но ничего не получилось. Можете подсказать, что я делаю не так?

```
browser.performActions([{
  type: 'key',
  id: 'keyboard',
  actions: [{ type: 'keyDown', value: '\uE008' }]
}])
$('tr.el-table__row:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)').click()
browser.performActions([{
  type: 'key',
  id: 'keyboard',
  actions: [{ type: 'keyUp', value: '\uE008' }]
}])
```